# Images are saving as .jpeg instead of .jpg on Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, image-editing

I've got my Google Chrome profile synced between my windows 10 machine and my MacOS 12.4 machine.

When I save a JPG formatted image from the internet, be it from a photo editing app, exporting from Figma, saving from Google SERPs, even if the extension of the image is `.jpg` on MacOS it always renames the extension to `.jpeg` rather than `.jpg`

I appreciate to many folk this makes no difference, but I'm not asking that, I have plenty of reasons to want to keep the original extension.

This only happens on the MacOS version of the Chrome profile.

When I use Edge/Firefox on MacOS it saves it correctly as `.jpg`

So it seems to be something related to MacOS + Chrome that's doing this.

I've been Googling loads but finding a whole lot of junk online and nothing helpful.

Does anybody else know how to change this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: What specifically have you tried already from the things you found?

Comment: Nothing because none of the results have been relevant lol

Comment: Do you have any extensions in Chrome, does the problem also occur with all of them disabled? If you create a new user account in your Mac and try it there, does it happen as well?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, tried incognito and a guest profile without extensions and it still does it.

Comment: Can you try with a new macOS user account? It may not be chrome profile related.

Comment: same problem here. is it a mac/chrome thing?

Comment: Note that strictly there are no JPG formatted images they are all JPEG formatted.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a Finder setting.

In Finder, from the 'Finder' top menu drop down menu (whew), select 'Preferences', select the 'Advanced' tab and then tick to enable 'Show all filename extensions'.

Now, in your save-as dialog, the original filename and extension will auto fill in the dialog allowing you to simply click save and retain .jpg for example.

Comment: I tried methods provided by @Philip Ingram, and the files being saved became ".jpg". So it seems like a "problem" with Chrome itself, when not knowing the extension you want to save, it saves image files to ".jpeg" format.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Chrome extension or rename file manually

There are two ways I've found so far working for me.

**1st way** : Use [Save Image As Type](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-image-as-type/gabfmnliflodkdafenbcpjdlppllnemd?hl=en) *Chrome extension*. When you right click on an image, it should propose you an option "Save image as JPG/PNG/WebP", select "JPG" when the menu appears and it should save the file as `.jpg` and not as `.jpeg`.

**2nd way** : *Rename the file manually*. When you have downloaded an image, go to Finder, find the image you've just downloaded and modify the file extension to `.jpg`. I am aware this is really tiresome but that's why I proposed the first solution which I find way more convenient.

Good luck! :)